# Incorporating ClassKit protocols into Objective-C++ project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, protocols, objective-c++

I'm trying to incorporate ClassKit for Apple's Classroom Manager into existing Objective-C++ apps under Xcode 10.0 and ios 11.4 and am having trouble with the Xcode-generated swift bridging header, MyProject-Swift.h, not recognizing a ClassKit protocol, CLSDataStoreDelegate.

CLSDtaStoreDelegate inherits from NSObjectProtocol, which the documentations says is fundamental to all Objective-C objects and is imported into Swift with the Name NSObjectProtocol. (It's not clear what "imported into Swift" means - is it making a swift version of an Objective-C protocol with the same name?)

CLSDataStoreDelegate is declared in a Swift file, MenuLibrary.swift:

```
@objcMembers
class MenuLibrary : NSObject, CLSDataStoreDelegate
{
    @objc
    static var mShared = MenuLibrary()

    @objc
    var mArrMainTopics : [MainTopic] = []

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }
...
}


class dummySwiftClass : NSObject
{
    required init (coder aDecoder : NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError ("init (coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

If the bridging header is imported into an Objective-C++ .mm file the error occurs, even if the .mm file has no swift code.

```
// AppDelegate.mm

#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

The relevant results in the xcode-generated Swift bridging header are:

```
@class CLSContext;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15ObjectiveC_Test11MenuLibrary")
@interface MenuLibrary : NSObject <CLSDataStoreDelegate>
SWIFT_CLASS_PROPERTY(@property (nonatomic, class, strong) MenuLibrary * _Nonnull mShared;)
+ (MenuLibrary * _Nonnull)mShared SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
+ (void)setMShared:(MenuLibrary * _Nonnull)value;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray<MainTopic *> * _Nonnull mArrMainTopics;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (CLSContext * _Nullable)createContextForIdentifier:(NSString * _Nonnull)identifier parentContext:(CLSContext * _Nonnull)parentContext parentIdentifierPath:(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nonnull)parentIdentifierPath SWIFT_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
@end

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15ObjectiveC_Test15dummySwiftClass")
@interface dummySwiftClass : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (nonnull instancetype)new SWIFT_DEPRECATED_MSG("-init is unavailable");
@end
```

The error occurs in the fourth line where CLSDataStoreDelegate is:
"No type or protocol named 'CLSDataStoreDelegate' MyProject-Swift.h in file included from AppDelegate.mm".

Other posts have listed adding "@objc" to the protocol declaration, but CLSDataStoreDelegate is part of ClassKit, which I have no access to.  I tried subclassing it but that didn't work.

It appears that the bridging header includes all Swift classes, even if they have no "@objc" properties or functions, as evidenced by the dummySwiftClass and other classes not listed. This could be a problem trying to compartmentalize Swift files. I've also found that the bridging header doesn't recognize structures and enumerations in swift files.

If the "CLSDataStoreDelegate" is removed from MenuLibrary I can access properties and functions in Swift classes from Objective-C++ .mm files, but the delegate is necessary if I am to use ClassKit with Objective-C++ files.  It appears that ClassKit was designed with pure Swift projects in mind, but it would be prohibitive to translate my apps completely to Swift.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried importing `ClassKit` in the `.mm` file, before importing `"MyProject-Swift.h"`?

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  Would that be because ClassKit is written in C or C++? I haven't incorporated all the Objective-C++ files and am just testing the ClassKit end, but so far so good.

Comment: If you want to be able to access a module's classes, you need to import the module. That's pretty all there is to it, regardless the language of the file you're doing the import into.